# php htacess pretty urls add .html at end

Tags: php

I'm using the below .htaccess file in my application.
It's working fine so far. It's giving SEO friendly URL.
But I need to add .html extension at the end.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Anupama/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product-details(?:\.php)?\?product_id=([^\s&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ Product/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /products(?:\.php)?\?pid=([^\s&]+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ Categories/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# PHP hiding rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^Product/([A-Z,0-9-]+)$ product-details.php?product_id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^Categories/([A-Z,0-9-]+)$ products.php?pid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I got it. RewriteRule ^ Product/%1.html? [R=302,L,NE]. Added like this

Comment: If you've solved your problem, feel free to self-answer your question as it may be useful to future viewers of this question.